# Apache httpd virtual host SSL Certificate

Tags: apache, ssl, virtualhost

I'm setting up Apache as a reverse proxy giving https access to a service hosted on our intranet.

Apache httpd is running, and i've set up a virtual host as below.

```
NameVirtualHost *:443

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName my.domain.com

    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/my.domain.com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/mykey.key

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://128.0.0.120:8083/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://128.0.0.120:8083/

</VirtualHost>
```

I've generated a self signed certificate, and placed the files in /etc/pli/tls/cert/... as above, however when I browse to this page, i'm informed about the self signed certificate for the machine name, not the one specified in the VirtualHost. The certificate for the machine name is included by `/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf` by the line `SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/localhost.crt` this is all in the `<VirtualHost _default_:443>` section.

I was expecting my more specific VirtualHost to override the *default* settings, however it appears this is not the case. What should I do to correctly override the SSLCertificateFile instruction.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for your configuration to work as you intend it to, you need both the server and the client to support Server Name Indication. See :

https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHostsWithSNI

Comment: Thanks, that looks like what I need. Unfortunately i'm on RHEL 5.2, yum installs version 2.2.3 of Apache httpd. I think we'll be moving to 6.3, so will make those changes once I have a new environment.